# onActivityResult(int, int, Intent) is undefined for the type Object

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I am getting the error on "onActivityResult" stating "onActivityResult(int, int, Intent) is undefined for the type Object"

I've looked at people that have had the same problem and they've said that it's caused due to poorly placed curley braces. I have tried to re-position them but keep getting more and more errors.

hopefully someone could help me out with this:

```
package com.website.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class ListmenuActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listmenu);

    EditText CPU = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView4);
    CPU.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent CPUList = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    CPUList.class);
            startActivityForResult(CPUList, 1);

        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        if (requestCode == 1)
            ;

        Intent i = getIntent();
        String product = data.getStringExtra("product");
        EditText CPU = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView4));
        CPU.setText(product);

    }

    EditText RAMList = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
    RAMList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent RAMList = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    RAMList.class);
            startActivityForResult(RAMList,1);

        }

        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                Intent data) {

            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                if (requestCode == 1)
                    ;

                Intent i = getIntent();
                String product = data.getStringExtra("product");
                EditText RAM = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView4));
                RAM.setText(product);

            }
        }

    });

}

}
```

Comment: why two times added the same method... and what is the big issue with finding the missing bracket?

Comment: 1. there are 2 `onActivityResult()` methods.
2. Second one is inside RAMList.setOnClickListener() check them first

Comment: There is 2 onActivityResult() because I have 2 ListViews set up. Once the user selects on either EditText CPU or RAM, it then opens up a list view with CPU or RAM products in it, Then once the user selects a product, it will then set the corresponding product in the EditText CPU or RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RAMList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    // ...
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

This is not going to work as you expect. That `onActivityResult` method will **never** be called.

`onActivityResult` is a method of an `Activity`, invoked by the Android runtime whenever that activity receives the result of another activity which it launched through `startActivity(ForResult)`. You are trying to define it on a class solely implementing the `View.OnClickListener` interface, which does not have an `onActivityResult` method. It does not override any method of a superclass or interface, it's just a new method which has no special purpose at all.

You are passing that class instance to `setOnClickListener`, which is only concerned with calling `onClick` - as that is in the `View.OnClickListener` interface. It doesn't know that there's an `onActivityResult` method in that object, and it simply *doesn't care*.

If you want to get this working, you need to put that code in the `onActivityResult` of your `ListmenuActivity`. Since that class inherits `Activity`, its `onActivityResult` will be called for all activities launched by `startActivity(ForResult)`. You'll need to differentiate between your two separate launches so you know what to do for the given result. That's why Android provides you with a `requestCode`: give your different launches different `requestCode`s and you'll be able to separate them when you receive their results in `onActivityResult`.

Thus, your `ListmenuActivity.onActivityResult` method should look like:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        // Handle result of CPUList
    } else if (requestCode == 2) {
        // Handle result of RAMList
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

You would launch your subactivities with `startActivityForResult(CPUList, 1)` and `startActivityForResult(RAMList, 2)`.

(Side note: it's very confusing if you name two different variables `RAMList` - an `EditText` and an `Intent` - in the same scope.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to call:

```
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

and this code do nothing:

```
if (requestCode == 1)
    ;
```

You can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

there is already `onActivityResult()` delared no need to define it two times.

another thing is you had mention 2nd `onActivityResult()` in `onClickListener()` which is wrong.

Wrong Points in your code

1. onClickListener() can not have onActivityResult() in it.
2. you don't need to do `findViewById()` at `onActivityResult()` as you had already done it at `onCreate().`

problem of missing brackates

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   // your code
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        Intent i = getIntent();
        String product = data.getStringExtra("product");
        CPU.setText(product);
    }
}
```

you just need to replace this onActivityResult() with these one.

Comment: I need to declare it twice because I have 2 ListViews set up. Once the user clicks on a product from the ListView, it then sets the text in the ListView corresponding to the products "CPU" and "RAM"

Comment: @Jack instead of this you can bind both EditText at onCreate() and just make them visible/invisible and setText() on onActivityResult().